# Meteor assign _id when creating user

Tags: meteor

I want to assign the _id of meteor user when I create them. `Meteor.createUser()` doesn't seem to allow this.

Is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accounts.onCreateUser exists on the server to allow customisation of the user doc before it is inserted. The code below modifies the doc, the new user appears in the db, and the user on client gets logged in with customised _id.

```
//in server js code
Accounts.onCreateUser( function( options, user){
  user._id = 'myId' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 1000 ) + 1;
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile; //careful not to drop the profile if it exists
  return user;
});
```

Function documentation and a very similar example are here - http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser